# Pivot Table for multiple data points in new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to VBA. i work a lot with excel data crunching and want to automate it. i want to write a code to create a pivot table for each tested parameter; my file has many columns with test name, the first 3 are "Serial#"    "Read Point",   "Bin#" and after that different tests for aexample  "CAL_0.604_0.596 V "    "ENABLE_-0.2_-0.8 V "   "PG_-0.2_-0.8 V "86 and so on (could be up to 200+). i have for example 45 serial numbers and read point is the test point for each stress T0, T200, T500, T1000. so as you can see i have a big array. how i modify this code to loop test names from my columns names and build a pivot table for each of the tests when serial# and read point stays the same for all pivot charts. each pivot chart must be on a new sheet and sheet name is the same as the name in the column. Thanks a lot!! 
so far i got to this;

```
Sub Macro3()
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K226")).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), TableName:="PivotTable1"

    Set PT = Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    With PT.PivotFields("Serial#")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With PT.PivotFields("Read Point # Temp Cycles")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With PT.PivotFields("CAL_0.604_0.596 V   ")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    'build Chart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$G$48")
End Sub
```